# How to use reduce in a functional programming style to parse YAML front matter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, functional-programming

I've got a file I want to parse with Javascript:

```
---
title: This is a great title
date: 2012-03-02 11:30:00 -04:00
published: false
---

data_one
data_two
data_three
```

From this, I only want to output:

```
['data_one', 'data_two', 'data_three']
```

So that means I need to skip the first five lines.

While I can easily make my script automatically skip the first five lines, I want it to be robust enough that it would skip the front matter even if there was an extra item added in there. This is my current implementation:

```js
const result = rawFileStr.split('\n')
  .reduce((acc, item) => {
    const endOfFrontMatter = acc === false && item === '---';
    const isFrontMatter = acc === false || item === '---';

    if (endOfFrontMatter) {
      return [];
    }

    return isFrontMatter ? false : acc.concat(item)
  }, [])
```

It basically sets the accumulator to `false` to indicate that it hit the first `---` and then upon hitting the second `---`, it returns an empty array.

It works, but all those if statements make me feel that this isn't the "functional way" to do this. Can someone shed light on how to do this with pure functional programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the front matter by replacing, then chaining to a split, and then ensuring that empty strings are not kept by using a filter:

```js
let text = document.querySelector('textarea').value;

let data = text
  .replace(/^---[\s\S]*?---/, '')
  .split(/\s+/)
  .filter(str => str.length);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<textarea>
---
title: This is a great title
date: 2012-03-02 11:30:00 -04:00
published: false
---
  
data_one
data_two
data_three
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression to split by the lines up to the first `---` that is not on the first line, and then get the remainder of that:

```
const result = rawFileStr.split(/^[^]*?\n---\n/).pop().split('\n');
```

```js
// Sample data
const rawFileStr = `---
title: This is a great title
date: 2012-03-02 11:30:00 -04:00
published: false
---
data_one
data_two
---
data_three`;

const result = rawFileStr.split(/^[^]*?\n---\n/).pop().split('\n');
console.log(result);
```

Or, without regular expression, you could use an immediately invoked function expression, that slices the array with items from after the index where the first `---` occurs (that is not on the first line):

```
const result = (items => items.slice(items.indexOf('---',1)+1))(rawFileStr.split('\n'));
```

```js
// Sample data
const rawFileStr = `---
title: This is a great title
date: 2012-03-02 11:30:00 -04:00
published: false
---
data_one
data_two
---
data_three`;

const result = (items => items.slice(items.indexOf('---',1)+1))(rawFileStr.split('\n'));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: My only issue with this answer is that if someone puts a line with an extra `---` anywhere in the file (after the front matter), then it won't actually be able to read all the content. Ideally, I only want to skip until the second `---`.

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer so the break is at the second `---`.